# Getting a short string from a long one without spaces

Tags: grep, cat

I have a file with a huge string without spaces in it (something like: "A":123,"B":456,"C":789...)

I want to get X amount of chars before and after a specific value (like what is around "B").

But, if I use cat, because the string doesn't have spaces, the whole string returns.

I tried `cat time_series.json  | grep "B" | cut -c1-50` but again the whole returned.

I tried `cat time_series.json  | grep "B" | cut -b 1-400` but it only returned the start (and my string is in the middle)

What can I do?

Comment: Not an answer, but since you're looking at json files, [jq](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) or [fx](https://github.com/antonmedv/fx) may be more appropriate for data extraction.

Comment: Just a note, if the entire file is one string with no spaces and no newlines, the `grep` will do nothing - either it will show the file or it won't. Additionally, your commands have a "useless use of cat" - you can just `grep "B" time_series.json` instead.

Comment: @enkorvaks - grep CAN do something - see the answer by Stephen Kitt.

Comment: @Ran `grep` can do something useful, the `grep` command above will not. At least, it won't do anything if there are no newlines in the file (which the description suggests).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can ask `grep` to only output matching patterns, and include wildcards for the appropriate number of characters around the marker you’re looking for; e.g.

```
grep -E -o '.{50}"B".{50}'
```

to show `"B"` with 100 characters of context.